# COM libraries refreshing on different CATIA versions

Tags: c#, com, libraries, catia

I'm developing applications on C# for three different versions of CATIA.
For some reason when I open a project after I opened X version of CATIA. I can't just republish the project because the libraries seem to update on build and it gets the libraries from the version of CATIA opened last. Which means I have to validate whether they will work or not on the version of CATIA the tool is meant for.

Is is possible to lock some specific libraries to the project and avoid this update on build/rebuild?

Comment: How do you include your libraries? You could consider to add the libraries as a reference.

Comment: They are added as references currently

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it done.
I wasn't using the reference paths option. Which seemed to do the trick.
It looks like the last version of catia opened registers it's libraries, therefore VS gets them directly. Using the reference path and adding the folder for the catia version of the tool allows Catia to search for the correct ones first

Thanks